# ELMAH within a themed page error

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, elmah

I have a themed page whereby the theme is chosen inside a http module.

```
public void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page p = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

    if (p != null)
    {
        //get theme
        string theme = GetTheme(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);

        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Loading theme {0}", theme));

        //set theme of page
        p.Theme = theme;
    }
}
```

Now when I request the elmah.axd the following exception is thrown:

Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. (e.g. ).

When I disable the http theme module everything is fine and elmah.axd page is shown. I think this is a small bug inside the ErrorLogPage. The ErrorLogPage should cope with the fact that a theme can be given to the page OR should ignore the given theme at all.

For now I use the workaround:

`private const string ELMAH_ERROR_PAGE = "Elmah.ErrorLogPage";`

```
        if (p.GetType().FullName != ELMAH_ERROR_PAGE)
        {
            p.Theme = theme;
        }
```

Do you have any better ideas or thoughts?

Gr

Martijn

The Netherlands

Comment: Does the page, or master page, have a `runat="server"` in the `head` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to your problem has been answered before:
 [Exclude certain pages from using a HTTPModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956/exclude-certain-pages-from-using-a-httpmodule).

> You could use an HTTPHandler instead
>   of an HTTPModule. Handlers let you
>   specify a path when you declare them
>   in Web.Config.
>
> ```
> <add verb="*" path="/validate/*.aspx" type="Handler,Assembly"/>
> ```
>
> If you must use an HTTPModule, you
>   could just check the path of the
>   request and if it's one to be
>   excluded, bypass the validation.