# IIS Dynamic IP restrictions in web.config location

Tags: asp.net, iis, ip-restrictions

I'm trying to use [IIS Dynamic IP Restrictions](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions) to throttle requests from the same IP. I have the module running and the requests are nicely throttled if I edit the dynamic restrictions settings from the IIS UI. This is nice however I need to have different rates on different URLs. Login should be for example more strict than static resources. I'm trying to use `locations` in web.config to achieve this.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="foo">
  <system.webServer>   
    <security>     
      <dynamicIpSecurity enableLoggingOnlyMode="true">       
         <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="1" 
            requestIntervalInMilliseconds="5000" />
      </dynamicIpSecurity>
   </security>  
  </system.webServer> 
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't apply. I'm quite sure it has nothing to do with my app because it doesn't work also on a static web with one HTML file. I'm also quite sure that the location path is correct, because the requests are blocked if I add `...<deny users="*" />`.

Comment: Did you try to set `enableLoggingOnlyMode` to `false`? According to [this page](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity) requests are not actually blocked when it is set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've tried true, false and also without the attribute. Unfortunately this has no effect on throttling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. From the module description:

> This module can be configured such that the analysis and blocking
>   could be done at the Web Server or the Web Site level.

Internally this is implemented as HttpModule (native HttpModule that is). HttpModule runs for every single request - location doesn't affect them. For reference check out
[Exclude certain pages from using a HTTPModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956/exclude-certain-pages-from-using-a-httpmodule)

So your only other option (if you need to support this exact module) is to organize your site to several mini-applications instead.

Like

/ -> root web application

/Content -> web application with static content

/Login -> web application with login functionality

And in every single mini-application create web.config with appropriate rules.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to have specific rules for specific rest service  methods, so mini-applications aren't option for me. I'll have to use a different application level throttling module... I'll accept the answer if nothing else pops up by tomorrow.