# Disable Dynamic IP restriction for specific endpoints Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, ip-restrictions

I am trying to use Dynamic IP Restriction for IP based request Throttling in ASP.NET, all the requests to my server are getting throttled as per "denyByRequestRate" element attribute specified in web.config. Now I want to exclude certain paths from being throttled (eg. "/Content" folder which contains all the static .js and .css files).

I tried having a separate child web.config for the "/Content" sub-directory to override the action. As per the accepted answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238717/iis-dynamic-ip-restrictions-in-web-config-location). But it doesn't work.

Also tried using "location" element in web.config to use "denyByRequestRate" for certain locations but that also doesn't work.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Did you  create an webapplication  in IIS for /content? because only adding the web.config is not enough.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/denybyrequestrate) says "The <denyByRequestRate> element is configured at the server or site level."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Dynamic IP restrictions in web.config location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238717/iis-dynamic-ip-restrictions-in-web-config-location)

Comment: @rene i am publishing the website on azure (webapp) hence adding the "/Content" virtual directory on azure portal as mentioned [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115290/add-virtual-directory-to-existing-website-on-azure. Does this seems correct?

Comment: did you tick the application box?

Comment: @SirRufo so you mean it is not possible to achieve this as it happens at the server level and yes it is the duplicate of the above question, I mentioned above the accepted answer doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @rene yes i ticked the application box.